# Computation Complexity for Golden Section method

Tags: reference-request, algorithms

I need to provide computational complexity for the algorithms in my work. One of the algorithms I have used is Golden Section method for line search. I took a look at "Nonlinear Programming" book by Bertsekas, but it did not mention the computation complexity. I have found from a paper which also has used Golden Section method, that the computation complexity is O(log(1/epsilon)), but I want to find a book or an appropriate reference for that, to cite in my work. Do you know any book or like that which has provided this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See Luenberger, D. G. "Linear and nonlinear programming." p.200: http://books.google.com.br/books?id=QY9BjisUT1gC&pg=PA200

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but how is it possible to show that the computation complexity is O(log(1/epsilon))?

Comment: The computational complexity here is **not** referring to *arithmetic complexity* but rather *oracle complexity*, so that the golden section method, which converges to an $\epsilon$-accurate solution at a linear rate (also known as geometric / exponential convergence in numerical literature), will make $O(\log (1 / \epsilon) )$ calls to the oracle (to compute the value of $f(x)$) --- thus @Shamisen's pointer is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you please let me know of any reference which shows/proves this?

Comment: Can you give me the link to the paper that you have read

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh  https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4786509

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [E. Bertolazzi's Lecture notes.](http://www.ing.unitn.it/~bertolaz/2-teaching/2011-2012/AA-2011-2012-OPTIM/lezioni/slides-m1D.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how is it possible to show that the computation complexity is O(log(1/epsilon))?

Comment: The proof is in the notes.

Comment: You're right. I was making a mistake in proving it.